# Photos I upload to my ruby-on-rails server look bad

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

showing bad quality image on ruby on rails websit
ruby script:

```
    <div align="center">

    <p align="center">
    <%= if property.images[0] then link_to image_tag 
        (property.images[0].image.url('700x525', :jpg)), 
         user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], 
         :property_id => property) end -%>
    </p>

    </div>
```

hot to improve the photo quality?

Comment: We're probably going to need more information than that. How is the image being displayed? Is it being scaled in any way? There's not much to go on here.

Comment: Yeah it's probably being scaled in the browser because you did something incorrect in your HTML or CSS, and that almost always makes the image look bad.  You need to upload an image that is the correct size, or fix your HTML/CSS, or generate a thumbnail for it somehow.

Comment: hi there, thanks for advice, I still have no idea how to make it better, if you want have a look what it like on line, please check out: http://pauls.smartagent.co.nz/users/28/properties/9088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loaded photo is 600x400px, I thought the website was displaying it as 533x354px, but it's not actually scaling it, it's just showing what's (probably) inside your div, and leaves the overflow invisible.

The photos I can see are actually low quality, are those the original ones? (If so, there's not much to do here, unfortunately!)

Comment: thank a lot, your are right, the reason is because original photos are not good.